NGINX SSL configurations sometimes point to the wrong domain with multiple virtual hosts
Question:
I am running an NGINX server with approximately 150 virtual host configurations. Occasionally, clients report that their SSL certificate is incorrect, and their domain points to another client's SSL certificate, which is not intended behavior.
Here is my current setup:
The configuration files are automatically generated in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ have random names.
To ensure the default configuration loads first, I renamed it to 0000-default. This default configuration uses a self-signed certificate.
Other domain configurations are managed by Certbot/Letsencrypt and have proper SSL certificates.
0000-default configuration:
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl/self_cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl/self_key.pem;

        return 301 http://$host;
}

Example client configuration:
server {
    server_name sub.example.com;

    location = /.well-known/security.txt {
        alias /etc/nginx/snippets/security.txt;
    }

    location /branded_placeholder {
        root /etc/nginx/snippets;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/dslkfjaldk.php;
    }

    location / {
        if ($request_uri = "/") {
            return 301 https://$host/branded_placeholder;
        }
        proxy_pass http://backend_dslkfjaldk;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = sub.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server_name sub.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

The Problem:
Sometimes, when accessing a domain, the wrong SSL certificate is served. For example, a domain might point to another client's domain. This happens sporadically and appears to be random, but it causes significant issues for my clients.
What I have tried:
Ensuring the default server configuration is loaded first by renaming it to 0000-default. Validating the order of configuration files.
My Questions:
Why does NGINX sometimes serve the wrong SSL certificate for certain domains?
How can I ensure NGINX consistently serves the correct SSL certificate for each domain?
Is there a better way to configure the default server in combination with Certbot/Let's Encrypt to avoid this issue?
Additional Information:
I am using Certbot to manage SSL certificates.
The server is running NGINX on Debian 12.
